# Fail to use "locate"

Tags: linux, search

I have a file named `Fubini's_theorem.html` under some directory. But both

```
locate "Fubini's_theorem"
```

or

```
locate Fubini
```

do not return anything.

The file has been there for months, and I am sure it is already in the database used by `locate`. So I wonder why the search is not successful? Thanks!

My OS is Ubuntu 10.10.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the `find` utility:

`find / -name Fubini 2> /dev/null`

`/` to search starting from /
`-name Fubini` look for a file with "Fubini" in it's name
`2> /dev/null` redirect errors to /dev/null.

The redirect is useful when searching from root because /proc directories aren't really there. /proc is a virtual filesystem and `find`ing through it is ... well just not right :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command to update the database of file indexes

```
/usr/bin/updatedb -e /mnt/data,/mnt/files,...
```

Theoretically this command should be in your crontab so that it's executed periodically. You could check your crontab by running

```
crontab -l
```

If it isn't in there you could add it manually.

Comment: @Tim: Have you checked in updatedb's config file, that you aren't limiting the search scope more than you think? .. `/etc/updatedb.conf`

Comment: `-e` adds entries to PRUNEPATHS... This restricts the scope rather the expanding it.

Comment: Thanks! The file has been there for months, and newer files can be searched, so the database should be updated to have its record. Does my usage have any problem? @fred: The directory is already in PRUNEPATHS.

Comment: @Tim.. The directory which contains your file should **not** be in PRUNEPATHS. . . PRUNEPATHS means "do not look in those paths" ... Also: It may, or may not, suit your situation, but on my personal desktop I always run sudo updatedb. (I use Ubuntu 10.04)